# Python : Celery, How can I make it run in background?

Tags: python, api, celery, seconds

I use celery, with python 3 and supervisor in Ubuntu.

I've been working to make a new API, which will get an image from the internet using PIL(Pillow) and save it in a server.

However the problem is that I use Celery as scheduler and in the original API it returns the result in a milisecond, but when I use PIL, the wait becomes almost a second.

So as a solution, I am looking for a way to make the Celery worker run in the background.

Is it possible?

Comment: Is PIL used inside your API handler or in the function that is run by celery worker?

Comment: @avichalp yes, run by celery

Comment: @avichalp so since api does not perform in background, I have to call celery forcely and make it work in background, I wonder force call to celery is possible.

Comment: i do not understand. Celery is already running in background in the scenario that you described. What else do you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you probably want is to **daemonize** your Celery worker.

If you follow the steps provided in the Celery [running the worker as a daemon](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/tutorials/daemonizing.html) documentation you will be able to do that.

It is a bit of a complicated process, but it will allow the Celery worker to run in the background